# Delete directory exactly after hour since it was created

Tags: bash, shell, unix

In my app I create temp dirs every time user commits a certain action. Is there a chance to somwhow set 'expire' on that dirs? I need to delete those dirs exactly after hour since they were created.

I was thinking about CRONJOB but it will only **run** once an hour. This will not necessarily delete dirs exactly after one hour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why will the cron job only run once an hour?

Comment: I think he means the cronjob to check all could run at a set interval but it won't necessarily delete each dir exactly an hour after it was created. Jonathan Leffler's suggestion below should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`at`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/at.html) to schedule the removal of a particular directory.  This has the advantage that even if you modify the directory after it is created (adjusting its modify time - the create time is not stored), you will get the correct directory removed.  The granularity on `at` is 1 minute.